# Occasional refusal to boot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, windows-server-2003

My PC (custom-built, dual booting Server 2k3 and Arch Linux) will occasaionally refuse to boot up. It will pass the BIOS screen and I will get past NTLDR and SYSLINUX (in my case NTLDR is the primary bootloader on the MBR) but once the operating system starts to load it will OCCASIONALLY bug out with an error. In Windows this is either ntoskrnl.exe, ntfs.sys or SYSTEM being missing or corrupt. In Linux it's usually a kernel panic, different every time. This occurs every 5 or 6 times that I try to turn on the PC. When it does get past this stage correctly, everything works fine. Nothing is corrupt or broken.

I have tested the RAM with memtest86+ and found no errors. I have also run a number of HDD utilities (SMART, WD Data Lifeguard) and all have come back clean.

I actually posted about this (over 3 years ago!!) on a different site (http://www.computing.net/answers/hardware/hard-disk-corruption/67943.html) but nothing there was able to help. Now that I'm using this PC again, I'd like to resolve this issue.

Any suggestions?

System Specs:
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-EP45T-UD3P
CPU: Intel Core 2 Quad Q9400 2.66GHz
PSU: CORSAIR CMPSU-550VX 550W
Memory: 4GB DDR3 (G.SKIL, 2x2GB, PC3-10666)
HDD: Western Digital 640GB SATA (WD6401AALS)

Comment: Did you run memtest and the HDD tests continuously over a period of time or just once. Due to the intermittent nature of your fault, testing over a full 24 hour period would produce more trustworthy results

Comment: If you can get a null-modem serial cable and connect a second pc, appending few arguments to the linux boot command line would allow you to capture the boot log, so to share it, probably the panics are random as you say but there could be some element. http://linuxdeveloper.blogspot.it/2012/05/debugging-linux-kernel-over-serial-port.html